# Using Firebase in iOS framework

Tags: ios, firebase, frameworks, cocoapods

I created a Pod which is should use Firebase Analytics. The problem is if I try to use my Pod with my app it fails because it can't find the FirebaseAnalytics module inside my Pod. This is a known issue. So I tried to integrate Firebase without CocoaPods by copying the needed Firebase frameworks. I created the Pod, listed the Firebase frameworks in the Podspec file, but when I tried to build the app it failed with

> framework not found FirebaseInstanceID for architecture arm64

Any help would be appreciated!

Podspec looks like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
...
  s.platform     = :ios, "9.0"

  s.vendored_frameworks = 'FirebaseAnalytics.framework', 'FirebaseCore.framework', 'FirebaseInstanceID.framework', 'GoogleInterchangeUtilities.framework', 'GoogleSymbolUtilities.framework', 'GoogleToolboxForMac.framework'

  s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
  s.dependency 'PromiseKit', '~> 4.0'
  s.dependency 'KeychainAccess', '~> 3.0'
  s.dependency 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8'
  s.dependency 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.1'
  s.dependency 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 3.1.3'
  s.dependency 'JTAppleCalendar', '~> 6.0'

  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'SWIFT_VERSION' => '3' }
...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that CocoaPods supports static frameworks, it's possible to have FirebaseAnalytics and other static frameworks as dependencies, if you make a static_framework CocoaPod. Change FirebaseAnalytics back to `s.dependency` and add the following to the podspec:

> s.static_framework = true